# Swiper галерея с навигацией универсальная, на одной странице много галерей

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper

Подскажите как можно реализовать Swiper галерею  универсальную, точней как можно написать код на JS чтобы он подходил для всех галерей. Галерея состоит из слайдера и навигации сладов.
Пример, есть галерея и нужно эту галерею сделать на одной странице 30 шт таких одинаковых и чтобы они не конфликтовали, а параллельно все работали сами.

```
    const galleryThumbs1 = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs1', {
  spaceBetween: 10,
  slidesPerView: 4,
  freeMode: true,
  watchSlidesVisibility: true,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,

  breakpoints: {
        1200: {
            spaceBetween: 10,
             slidesPerView: 4,
        },
        992: {
            spaceBetween: 10,
             slidesPerView: 4,
        },
        768: {
            spaceBetween: 10,
             slidesPerView: 4,
        },
        576: {
            spaceBetween: 10,
             slidesPerView: 4,
        },
        320: {
            spaceBetween: 2,
             slidesPerView: 4,
        },

    }
});
const galleryTop1 = new Swiper('.gallery-top1', {
  spaceBetween: 42,

  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.h-gallery-next',
    prevEl: '.h-gallery-prev',
  },
  thumbs: {
    swiper: galleryThumbs1,
  },
});

 // gallery inner page horisontal thumbs menu
const galleryThumbs2 = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs2', {
  spaceBetween: 10,
  slidesPerView: 4,
  freeMode: true,
  watchSlidesVisibility: true,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,

  breakpoints: {
        1200: {
            spaceBetween: 10,
             slidesPerView: 4,
        },
        992: {
            spaceBetween: 10,
             slidesPerView: 4,
        },
        768: {
            spaceBetween: 10,
             slidesPerView: 4,
        },
        576: {
            spaceBetween: 10,
             slidesPerView: 4,
        },
        320: {
            spaceBetween: 2,
             slidesPerView: 4,
        },

    }
});
const galleryTop2 = new Swiper('.gallery-top2', {
  spaceBetween: 42,

  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.h-gallery-next2',
    prevEl: '.h-gallery-prev2',
  },
  thumbs: {
    swiper:galleryThumbs2,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Универсального решения не нашел, пришлось просто в массив насоздавать кучу.

```
        let galleryClassNames = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
        if ( !$('.gallery-thumbs' + i.toString()).length) {
        break;
        }

        galleryClassNames.push(new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs' + i.toString(), {
            spaceBetween: 10,
            slidesPerView: 4,
            freeMode: true,
            watchSlidesVisibility: true,
            watchSlidesProgress: true,
            breakpoints: {
            1200: {
                spaceBetween: 10,
                slidesPerView: 4,
            },
            992: {
                spaceBetween: 10,
                slidesPerView: 4,
            },
            768: {
                spaceBetween: 10,
                slidesPerView: 4,
            },
            576: {
                spaceBetween: 10,
                slidesPerView: 4,
            },
            320: {
                spaceBetween: 2,
                slidesPerView: 4,
            },

            }
        })
        );


        new Swiper('.gallery-top' + i.toString(), {
        spaceBetween: 42,

        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.h-gallery-next' + i,
            prevEl: '.h-gallery-prev' + i,
        },
        thumbs: {
            swiper:galleryClassNames[i-1],
        },
        });

    }
```